# System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I run my application, it takes a break and shows me this message

> An exception of type
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in
>   System.Configuration.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred creating the configuration
>   section handler for docCart: Could not load file or assembly
>   'App_Code' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

And this is the code

```
using System.Configuration;
public class Configuration
{
    public static IDocCartConfiguration GetConfiguration()
    {
        return (IDocCartConfiguration)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("docCart");
    }
}
```

How can I handle it?

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Configuration; 
public class Configuration 
{ 
    public static IDocCartConfiguration GetConfiguration() 
    { 
        try
        {
            return IDocCartConfiguration)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("docCart");     
        }
        catch(ConfigurationErrorsException e)
        {
             /* do something with the exception */
        }
    } 
}
```